# PHP Regex to Java Regex

Tags: java, php, regex

Could anybody convert some PHP regex to Java regex for me? I'm new to java regex; don't know how I would go around doing it.

```
%\A(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[A-Z])(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[a-z])(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[0-9])\S{4,}\z%
```

Also, does anybody know how to check if desired email is a valid email address layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to remove the delimeter and double quote it.
Put the \w equivalent in the regex.
Note that if your input comes from an edit box that's single line,
you can replace the \A and \z anchors with ^$ but, I use \A and \z
when I have to dither newlines.

```
 #   "\\A(?=[-\\w]*[A-Z])(?=[-\\w]*[a-z])(?=[-\\w]*[0-9])\\S{4,}\\z"

 \A 
 (?= [-\w]* [A-Z] )
 (?= [-\w]* [a-z] )
 (?= [-\w]* [0-9] )
 \S{4,} 
 \z
```

Answer (score 1):

`\` in a string in java you need to escape it like `\\`

```
 %\\A(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[A-Z])(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[a-z])(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[0-9])\\S{4,}\\z%
```